# Move form when panel is clicked and dragged

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to make my form move (like you move windows on other applications) when I click and hold my panel element (which serves as top of the window cause I used custom made GUI).

Anyways, I managed to make it move but the problem is, the form moves to my current cursor position when I click on it instead of moving like a regular window (cause it reads the cursor's position and sets the form's location to that position, thus moving it unnecessary).

This is my code, what can I do to get it to work properly?

```
Dim Moving As Boolean = False


 Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
    Moving = True
    MouseMoveTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
    Moving = False
    MouseMoveTimer.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub MouseMoveTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MouseMoveTimer.Tick
    Me.Location = Cursor.Position
End Sub
```

New code

```
Dim diff As Point = Cursor.Position - curpoint
        Me.Location -= diff
        curpoint = Cursor.Position
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the location of the cursor in each timer tick, and see how much it changed in the next tick.
Then add that change to the Form's position.

Comment: I have tried that but I got weird inverse result, idk what's wrong. I added it to the main post

Comment: Probably because the x position needs to be added and the y position subtracted (or vice versa), try playing around with it. an inverse result is good because it's close to what you want.